# Analog power supply

Tags: power, analog

I am trying to decode PAL and therefor need some very low noise analog power and ground supply. Does anybody know a good way of making a small circuit to reduce noise as much as possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean decode PAL?

Comment: @Joel B - I would assume the PAL TV Standard ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a low-noise voltage regulator. Most are LDOs (Low Drop-Out), so you may need a pre-regulator. This has the advantage that the input voltage is already smooth and will already have low ripple.
The National [LP3999](http://www.national.com/ds/LP/LP3999.pdf) is an example of a low-noise regulator which can deliver 150mA and can handle input voltages to 6V.

Much of the quality of your supply also depends on surrounding components and PCB layout. Use sufficient decoupling, and keep your power supply far enough from your video signal.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you make a quiet power supply for analog sub-circuitry using a series inductor to draw power through followed by a capacitor.  Typically in practice that ends up being two capacitors; one or more small ones with very low series impedance for high frequency filtering and a larger electrolytic in parallel for low frequency.

Choosing a quieter regulator certainly helps, but the filtering after the regulator (as well as proper board design) is key.

You can see such a circuit on the suggested application of pretty much any ADC or micro which includes an ADC.  In your case, you might look at the data sheets and app notes for parts designed to solve your problem and see how they handle the power issues - for example the bt848 was a solution to your problem in the PCI-bus era, and would have had to derive its analog supply from the bus power (though possibly regulating it from a higher voltage than you would have available if you pursue the usb idea)